# Search data in different levels of json structure

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

Good day, I need to create a function to search information in a json structure,  in some case the searching use two parameters to search, for example  SKU and punctuation. In the case exist more than one meets the condition, must be stored in an array.

The json structure. This structure is only an example.

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "brush",
            "punctuation": 20,
            "componets": [
                {
                    "SKU": "24AC",
                    "name": "toothbrush",
                    "type": "cleaning item"
                },
                {
                    "SKU": "23AC",
                    "name": "hair brush",
                    "type": "cleaning item"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "glue",
            "punctuation": 15,
            "componets": [
                {
                    "SKU": "24Ak",
                    "name": "paper glue",
                    "type": "hardware store"
                },
                {
                    "SKU": "23Ak",
                    "name": "floor glue",
                    "type": "hardware store"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
]
```

I try to modify this function, but I have problems to search in the different levels of json. This function to search the info only in the first level of json structure.

```
search(dataSearch:any, objectData:any){

    let result = objectData.filter((data:any) => {
      return Object.keys(data).some((key:any) =>{
        return JSON.stringify(data[key]).trim().includes(dataSearch);
      });
    });
  }
```

dataSearch -> search parameter /
objectData -> the json object in which the search has to be performed

This is the json object for the last function.

```
[
    {
        "punctuation": 20,
        "SKU": "24AC",
        "name": "toothbrush",
        "type": "cleaning item"
    },
    {
        "punctuation": 20,
        "SKU": "23AC",
        "name": "hair brush",
        "type": "cleaning item"
    }
]
```

Comment: "_This is the json object for the last function._" do you mean this is what you pass as `dataSearch` argument, or is it your expected result?

Comment: @ghybs I mean the function can search any data only in the last json object, I need help to modify this function so that it could search the first json object and not the second one